# Image Click Selects drop down Item in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows form and I want the picture to have a drop down list and when I click on image the drop down menu appears. Is it possible to make dropdown menu on image or can we add picture on combo box?

I want it to be like if in youtube, we click our profile then some menu like setting name account etc appear.
I want to do the same.

Comment: So you want a ComboBox with Lists of Pictures, this wont work in the Default Control, you would have to code your own. Or take one from the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to solve it.

In addition, you need to fill in the content for the ContextMenuStrip Item.
[image: here]

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;           
    }   
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(pictureBox1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }
```

Result：

[image]

Comment: Can we do it with left click on mouse? Like now its opening with right click but I want it to open with left click

Comment: Well Thank you so much, It helps a lot, Thank you so so so much